# "TypeError: expected bytes, str found" when calling .MidiIn() from rtmidi-python

Tags: python-3.4, typeerror, python-wheel

I installed rtmidi_python for Python 3.4.2 from the *.whl* provided on http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, and the import works fine, but as soon as I call "rtmidi_python.MidiIn()", I get a TypeError as follows:

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import rtmidi_python
>>> rtmidi_python.MidiIn()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    rtmidi_python.MidiIn()
  File "rtmidi_python.pyx", line 72, in rtmidi_python.MidiIn.__cinit__ (rtmidi_python.cpp:1440)
TypeError: expected bytes, str found
```

As I understand, after some research, this means that the there's a mistake somewhere in the package itself or in the build of it, and there's nothing I can do about it, but I might be wrong. Can anyone confirm?

I use 3.4.2 because that is the version of Python used by the current version of Blender. I want to use rtmidi-python within the Blender Game Engine.
I am currently working on Windows 7 32 bit, and use *.whl*s to install packages as I do not have the necessary C++ compiler for regular pip installs.

For comparison, I previously installed rtmidi-python for 3.5.1, also from the adequate *.whl* provided on the link above, and there the command worked perfectly fine.

Should any necessary information be missing, feel free to ask. Thanks ahead if the answer comes as a comment and I don't get to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

While not a perfect solution, this can be fixed in the manner described by sehqlr here...https://github.com/superquadratic/rtmidi-python/issues/17

...by calling *MidiIn()* like this:

```
>>> rtmidi_python.MidiIn(b'in')
```

Comment: As said there this is a workaround specific to rtmidi.